# Repeated inheritance and static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance, type-erasure

I have a type eraser with the following inheritance structure:

```
                     Holder
    /                   |            \
    |                   |            |
Holder_A_1         Holder_B_1    Holder_C_1
    |                   |            ...
Holder_A_2         Holder_B_2
   ...                 ...
    |                   |
Holder_A_base     Holder_B_base  Holder_C_base
    |                   |            ...
Holder_A_base_2   Holder_B_base_2
   ...                 ...
    |                   |             |
Anchor                Anchor        Anchor
```

(The Anchor base class is repeated on purpose.)

Upon the object construction I construct a Holder object and cast it to Anchor* for storage and deletion. The cast is done via `Holder_A_base*` for disambiguation: `static_cast<Holder_A_base*>(static_cast<Anchor*>(this))`

My question is: is it legal to `static_cast` from `Anchor*` (constructed as explained above) to `Holder_B_base*` if I know for a fact that `Holder` object that is erased derives from both of these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is easier to understand if you rephrase it to be "is it legal to `static_cast` from `Holder_A_base_2 *` to `Holder_B_base *`?"  No, it isn't, and it won't compile.

Casting from `Anchor *` to `Holder_B_base *` will compile but will be Undefined Behavior unless the `Anchor` object pointed to is the one that is part of `Holder_B_base`.

If you need to cast from any `Anchor *` to class that it is not part of, you can use `dynamic_cast`.  This allows cross casts.